# SimpleApp.py doesn't exist

Tags: python, pyspark

There is a simpleApp example in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html  I wrote the same as specified in this example but I got the following error:

> File "/media/zhu/Data/My
>   Document/University/TimeOfInformation/Spark/SimpleApp.py", line 5, in 
>              sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App");   File
>   "/home/zhu/Programs/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 115, in **init**   File
>   "/home/zhu/Programs/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 172, in _do_init   File
>   "/home/zhu/Programs/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py",
>   line 235, in _initialize_context   File
>   "/home/zhu/Programs/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1064, in **call**   File
>   "/home/zhu/Programs/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 308, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. :
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: **Added file
>   file:/media/zhu/Data/My%20Document/University/TimeOfInformation/Spark/SimpleApp.py
>   does not exist**.     at 
>       oenter code hererg.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1364)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1340)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:491)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:491)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)  at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:491)  at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)     at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)     at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
>     at
>   py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
>     at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Does anyone see the reason?

Comment: Why is there a massive gap between My and Document?

Comment: what gap? it say simapp doesn't exist. But it does exist.

Comment: The about eight spaces between the words, can you not see the  `%20` in the filepath?

Comment: Not if you look at the traceback, in any case does `/media/zhu/Data/My                 Document` exist?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It exists in the first line.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It works when I moved the script to another folder whose path contains no space though I don't know why. Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ubuntu

Comment: Were you reading from a  usb?

Comment: No             but the script is located in a different disk from home directory

Comment: The only thing I can see that would be causing an issue is the  `%20`,  did it work from another folder on media/...?

Comment: Yes. I tried it just now. It turns out that it doesn't matter in which disk I put the script and that it works only when the path to the folder that contains it contains no space

Comment: I know in linux when some applications get passed a path with % that they can choke, not sure whether it is a java or pyspark issue.